# Why is CheckMarx flagging this code as an XSS vulnerability?

Tags: reactjs, checkmarx

This component is being flagged by CheckMarx as vulnerable. I don't understand why. I am not sure what extent CheckMarx understands React code, and I don't know how I would appease CheckMarx.

The error is `Client_DOM_XSS`: The application's render embeds untrusted data in the generated output with state, at line 25 of react-app\src\visualizer\Visualization.js. This untrusted data is embedded straight into the output without proper sanitization or encoding, enabling an attacker to inject malicious code into the output.

Can anyone help?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';


export default class Visualization extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            x: null,
        };
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
        if(!this.props.x) {
            this.setState({
                x: null,
            });
        } else if(this.props.x !== prevProps.x) {
            this.setState({
                x: this.props.x,
            });
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (<div>X: {this.state.x}</div>)
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a bug in checkmarx.

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet you provided is, indeed, not vulnerable to XSS.

I scanned the code snippet with Checkmarx's SAST (latest version) and couldn’t reproduce the result. Any chance you are using an old version?

It is also worth mentioning that in some cases, XSS may arise, for example, if the input is embedded inside the `srcdoc` attribute of an IFrame element (note that in the current snippet, it’s not possible to say if the state and props are influenced by user input).

I hope that helps.

Comment: The scan is run by Checkmarx Enterprise V9.4.4 HF10. Is that the latest version? After simplifying the code the props are hard-coded to simple inputs and this component is instantiated only once, not in an iFrame. The vulnerability is still highlighted.

Answer (score -1):

As a method of bypassing this for some period of time you can use given approach

**This given solution is a bypass of a given rule not the solution**

create a method named *content()* that would return a JSX. Which then can be referred from the **render()**.

Therefor you need to convert below fragment

```
render() {
    return (<div>X: {this.state.x}</div>)
}
```

Into this

```
content() {
    return (<div>X: {this.state.x}</div>)
} // <--- method returning JSX

render() {
    return this.content();
}
```

Now you are bypassing render embedment untrusted data in the generated output through state. This would resolve the given XSS error in checkmarkX.

Comment: Why is this necessary? Is this a bug with Checkmarx or it is actually vulnerable? I would have thought you need to have `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` set for this to be vulnerable, since it escapes HTML output by default.